# Using lambda to return more than one column

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have the following table:

```
                         TABLE_NAME  jace  building    equipment
0  R338_1_FAHU2_SUPAIR_TEMP          NaN       NaN        NaN
1  R1001_1_R1005_1_FAHU_1_CO2_SEN2   NaN       NaN        NaN
```

I wrote this sub-function that analyses one column and (should) return three.

```
 def fill(tablename='R338_1_FAHU2_SUPAIR_TEMP'):
    jace,building,equipment=re.findall('(^[RP].*?_[1-9])_*(.*?)_(F.*)',tablename)[0]
    if not len(building):
        building=re.findall('(.*)_',jace)[0]
    return jace,building,equipment
```

this function returns for the first row

```
('R338_1', 'R338', 'FAHU2_SUPAIR_TEMP')
```

I want to insert those into jace,building, and equipment columns above
I tried this:

```
df[['jace','building','equipment']]=df['TABLE_NAME'].apply(lambda x: (fill(x)))
```

it gave me

> ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an
> iterable

I also tried `axis=1` inside `apply()`, which seems to contradict with lambda for some reason

Any ideas how to make it work?
(I can use `fill(x)[0], fill(x)[1]`, which should solve the issue, but that feels like hard-coding)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function should return a Series:

```
def fill(tablename='R338_1_FAHU2_SUPAIR_TEMP'):
    jace,building,equipment=re.findall('(^[RP].*?_[1-9])_*(.*?)_(F.*)',tablename)[0]
    if not len(building):
        building=re.findall('(.*)_',jace)[0]
    return pd.Series([jace,building,equipment])

df[['jace','building','equipment']] = df['TABLE_NAME'].apply(fill)
```

output:

```
                        TABLE_NAME     jace building          equipment
0         R338_1_FAHU2_SUPAIR_TEMP   R338_1     R338  FAHU2_SUPAIR_TEMP
1  R1001_1_R1005_1_FAHU_1_CO2_SEN2  R1001_1  R1005_1    FAHU_1_CO2_SEN2
```

Now you could also use vectorial code for efficiency:

```
(df['TABLE_NAME']
 .str.extract('(?P<jace>^[RP].*?_[1-9])_*(?P<building>.*?)_(?P<equipment>F.*)')
 .assign(building=lambda d: d['building'].mask(d['building'].eq(''),
                                               d['jace'].str.extract('(.*)_',
                                                                   expand=False)))
)
```

output:

```
      jace building          equipment
0   R338_1     R338  FAHU2_SUPAIR_TEMP
1  R1001_1  R1005_1    FAHU_1_CO2_SEN2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `result_type="expand"`

Can you try the following:

```
def fill(tablename='R338_1_FAHU2_SUPAIR_TEMP'):
    jace,building,equipment = re.findall(
        '(^[RP].*?_[1-9])_*(.*?)_(F.*)',
        tablename['TABLE_NAME'])[0]
    if not len(building):
        building=re.findall('(.*)_',jace)[0]
    return jace, building, equipment

df[['jace','building','equipment']] = df[['TABLE_NAME']].apply(
    fill, axis=1, result_type="expand")
```

Comment: There is no `result_type` parameter for [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) (only for DataFrame)

Comment: @mozway Yeah, I modified it to dataframe apply. Your solution looks cool..